# Incrementing a variable in VB.net with a button

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I'm trying to increment my variable on a button click.  It increments only once.  It seems as though it's getting lost when it reloads the page.

I'm using the following code:

```
Dim ItemSelect As New ArrayList()
Dim Quantities As New ArrayList()
Dim itemQtyOrdered As Integer

Public Sub ShtickDataList_ItemCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles ShtickDataList.ItemCommand

    If e.CommandName = "ViewCart" Then
        Response.Redirect("~/ShoppingCart.aspx")
    End If

    If e.CommandName = "addToCart" Then
        Dim itemQuantity As DropDownList = e.Item.FindControl("QuantityDropDown")
        itemQtyOrdered = itemQuantity.SelectedValue
        ItemSelect.Add(e.CommandArgument)
        Quantities.Add(itemQtyOrdered)

        Session("itemInCart") = ItemSelect
        Session("quantities") = Quantities

        viewInvoice()
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub viewInvoice()

    Dim itemSelected As ArrayList = DirectCast(Session("itemInCart"), ArrayList)
    Dim QuantityofItem As ArrayList = DirectCast(Session("quantities"), ArrayList)
    Dim conn As SqlConnection
    Dim comm As SqlCommand
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader
    Dim purimConnection2 As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Purim").ConnectionString
    conn = New SqlConnection(purimConnection2)

    comm = New SqlCommand("SELECT ProductName FROM Products WHERE ProductID = @ProductID", conn)

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ItemSelect.Count - 1
        comm.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
        comm.Parameters("@ProductID").Value = ItemSelect(i)
    Next

    Try
        conn.Open()
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader()
        ViewCartlink.Text = "View Cart: (" & ItemSelect.Count & ")"
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I do not see any variable being incremented in the code that you provided, nor is there a button click.

Comment: Surely if you are 'reloading' the page it would reset your variables?

Comment: what i need is to add items to my array an d then that i loops through the array. how do I avoid reloading the page each time?

Comment: Can you please point out the variable you are expecting to increment so others can follow your logic?

Comment: Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ItemSelect.Count - 1
        comm.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", Data.SqlDbType.Int)
        comm.Parameters("@ProductID").Value = ItemSelect(i)
    Next

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you may be referring to `ItemSelect` and `Quantities` lists. You need to look for them in `Session` and only create them if they are not in the `Session`. I am rusty on VB.NET, so this is C# version. In `Page_Load`:

```
ItemSelect = (ArrayList)Session["itemInCart"];
if (ItemSelect == null)
{
  ItemSelect = new ArrayList();
  Session["itemInCart"] = ItemSelect;
}
```

and the same for `Quantities`.

Also, your loop in `viewInvoice` method is wrong. For more than one item in `ItemSelect` list you are adding multiple parameters with the same name. You probably only wanted to do it once with

```
comm.Parameters("@ProductID").Value = ItemSelect(ItemSelect.Count - 1)
```

Comment: I get it, its overiding the first one. So how do I fix that?

Comment: thanks. Im going to try this but how do I get arount the perameter problem?

Comment: Your sql has only one parameter in it. Therefore you need to add only one parameter to you command. In any event, why are you doing it if you are not using the `reader`?

Comment: when i declare the array only if it hasnt been done yet  like you said then the variables are not global

Comment: I have not shown any declaration, only assignment. I do not know the proper VB.NET syntax for declaring a class member with value being `null` (`Nothing`).

Comment: thanks for you help. I just submitted a new question explainig better what im looking for including the modifications you made.  hopefully someone who likevb can help